# What is the purpose of the passout parameter when using openssl genrsa

Tags: openssl

Can anyone explain, what is the purpose of the **passout** parameter when using **openssl genrsa**?

I already read the manual, 
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/genrsa.html
but I can't imagine what is meant with: 
"the output file password source." Can anyone give a good concrete example.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose passout (and passin) parameters are to automate openssl so that it doesn't prompt for a password but will get the password from somewhere else.  I would recommend you read the [PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl.html) section of the documentation for usage.

As for a genrsa example is if you run the command:

> openssl genrsa -out private.pem -aes256 2048

will create a 2048bit rsa private key and encrypt it with aes256 and write it to the file private.pem.  Opensssl will prompt you for password to be used to generate a encryption key for aes256.

If you wish to automate it in a script file you can:

> openssl genrsa -out private.pem -aes256 -passout pass:abc123 2048

This command will not prompt for the password and the password for the private key is "abc123".

It is not recommended that you use this style unless security is not a issue.